# Use predicate expression with NEST in .NET 5

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, repository-pattern, nest

Is it possible to configure in NEST (.NET 5) a way to use a default predicate expression (Default Query Filter) for all NEST queries (*GetAsync*, *GetManyAsync*, *SearchAsync*, *ExistsAsync*, ...) performed on any index?

The idea would be to work as it is done in Entity Frameork, using ***HasQueryFilter***, for example:

```
builder.HasQueryFilter(m => m.DeletedAt == null);
```

Where in all queries, the expression `DeletedAt == null` is inserted into the query.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of `GlobalQueryStringParameters` method from `ConnectionSettings` but seems query parameter will be sent to those supporting query parameter (`q`) like [search endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-search.html#search-api-query-params-q).

And you won't be able to use e.g. `GetAsync` because it doesn't support `q` parameter.

```
var indexName = "test";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
connectionSettings.EnableDebugMode();
connectionSettings.DefaultIndex(indexName);
var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nameValueCollection.Add("q", "deletedAt: null");
connectionSettings.GlobalQueryStringParameters(nameValueCollection);
var elasticClient = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

var searchResponse = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<EsDocument>(s => s.Query(q => q.Term("id", 1)));
```